# How to replace an object's PascalCase keys with an additional space in between?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm populating some fields using JSON. The keys I load are all camel cased and look something like the below...

```
{
  "ThisIsAnother": {},
  "ThisIsAnExample": {}
}
```

I'm pulling them back fine, but I need to format them to make them correct, something like

```
{
  "This Is Another": {},
  "This Is An Example": {}
}
```

Is this possible with JS or should I format my JSON in another way?

Comment: Can you be more specific then *I need to format them*?

Comment: Sorry, amended @AshayMandwarya

Comment: is that an array of objects like this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always split on capital casing of all keys for your object.
Though, I believe users should adapt and use proper json key naming.

```js
let data = {
  "ThisIsAnother": {}
};

Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
  let newKey = key.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ");
  data[newKey] = data[key];
  delete data[key];
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks @JonathanHamel, what do you mean adapt and use proper json key naming?

Comment: Proper key could be "thisIsAnother" in that case. https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml?showone=Property_Name_Format#Property_Name_Format

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex with a [capture group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_parenthesized_substring_matches_2) for `[A-Z]` to [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) them with an extra space

(Note: This creates a new object. If you want the same object mutated, you can use this regex with what accepted answer is suggesting)

```js
let data = {
  "ThisIsAnother": {},
  "ThisIsAnExample": {}
};

const newObj = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, k) => {
  let newKey = k.replace(/\B([A-Z])/g, " $1");
  acc[newKey] = data[k];
  return acc
},{});

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const json = {
  ThisIsAnExample: {},
  ThisIsAnother: {}
};

const result = Object.entries(json).reduce((all, [key, value]) => {
  all[key.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g).join(" ")] = value

  return all;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```